# center hs.loading instead of relative calculation

Tags: loading, highslide

i like to center the highslide "loading" like this:

```
.highslide-loading {
  display: block;
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
  padding: 24px;
  margin:-40px 0 0 -40px;
  text-indent:-9999em;
  background:#FFFFFF url(img/hslide_loader_white.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

but the highslide script puts out an inline style like this:

```
element.style {
  left: 134px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  z-index: 1003;
}
```

i found this thread in the old support forum, that explains how to access the loading object: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1796&p=7975

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onShowLoading = function (sender) {
   var width = sender.thumbWidth;
   sender.loading.style.width = width +'px';
};
```

this also works with "position" but not with "top" or "left"

because:

> The top and left values are set after the onShowLoading event, so
>   those can not be edited by the event handler. You could edit the
>   highslide.js file itself to fix this. Another way would be to set a
>   marginLeft and marginTop to the loading label, and let Highslide do
>   top and left.

but - i have different usages of the highslide script and need to keep the codebase of highslide.js. Margins doesnt help me.

i did make a custom config script - but hs.loading is not accessible.

```
if (typeof(hs) != "undefined") {

  $.extend(true, hs || {}, {

    dimmingOpacity:0.75,
    ...,
    loading: hs.createElement('a', {
            className: 'highslide-loading',
            title: hs.lang.loadingTitle,
            innerHTML: hs.lang.loadingText,
            href: 'javascript:;'
        }, {
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '50%',
            opacity: hs.loadingOpacity,
            zIndex: 1
        }, hs.container
    )

  });

}
```

also in hs.overrides (http://highslide.com/ref/hs.overrides) there is no access to the loader

is there a way to get the loader centered in window?

if not - i stop investigating ;-)

Comment: Does this help at all: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1483 also, make sure that the name is not replaced by a internal function of highslide. Naming your css class to something that highslide will later redefine causes these types of issues.

Comment: this would help me if i could edit highslide.js source, but for environmental reasons its not possible to do so.


So i woudl need to access that function width $.extend() but i think its not possible

Comment: When creating the loading object, can you try assining style objects to it then? obj.style.width = "100px" for instance?

Comment: all styles but "top" and "left" because they are calculated after hs.Expander.prototype.onShowLoading()